# Add Options Menu in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have tried to add options menu to my application, but when
adding a Create Options Menu to the code it is not used.  It looks like this:

[image: IDE snapshot showing unused handler]

I used in this page on Fragment Activity and implements Tab Listener.

What is the right way to add the Options Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the fragment activity** where you want to have the menu
(Make sure you are importing *android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity*):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In **res/menu folder** you should have this file:
**main_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemId"    
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/yourString"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: thanks i try it but i get the error "cannot resolve the method getMenuInflater()"

Comment: I forgot you were using fragments. See my edited answer!

Comment: its not fragment its FragmentActivity.. so getActivity() method is not working in this case..

Comment: See my edited answer again, this soul work. It's working on my app right now using Fragment Activities

Comment: Did you check the import?